# Java Streams: modifying return collection to a custom type with Collectors.toCollection

Tags: java, java-stream, doubly-linked-list

How can I modify the return collection to that of a custom type? 
I have a custom Linkedlist Object that I would like to replace after doing some type of operation on it.

Here's a simple example of what I would like to achieve:

```
myCustomList = myCustomList.stream()
                           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(user::getId))
                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(CustomLinkedList::new))
```

I get the following error from this `CustomlinkedList::new` piece of code.

> Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert CustomLinkedList to java.util.Collection

I guess I could just convert it to a default LinkedList Object, iterate over it and add the nodes one by one to my customLinkedList implementation, but that doesnt feel like a clean solution to me.

Here's a link to the customList I am using: [customLinkedList](https://github.com/williamfiset/data-structures/blob/master/com/williamfiset/datastructures/linkedlist/DoublyLinkedList.java) 
Is there a way to solve this problem?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on Ismail's proposal I managed to get the implementation for `Collector.of` like so:

```
.collect(Collector.<T, CustomLinkedList<T>>of(
                                     CustomLinkedList::new, 
                                     CustomLinkedList::add, 
                                     CustomLinkedList::cloneInto));
```

But now I get the following error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

---

**SOLUTION:**

I completely forgot I was using Spliterators.spliterator with a set size of 0. Fixing that to the current size of the list fixed the issue. Thank you all!

Comment: Could you show us your CustomLinkedList class?

Comment: @Ismail updated the question with a link of the list implementation

Comment: You should be putting all the info in the post instead of drip feeding information after a new issue comes up. Where is the implementation of `CustomLinkedList`?

Comment: @George There is a link in the question to the custom linkedlist that I am using, perhaps you missed it?

Comment: @George upvoted you for reminding me to look better next time. Updated the question with the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the `supplier` for the `collect` java stream using `Collector.of`:

```java
myCustomList = myList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(user::getId))
        .collect(Collector.of(
                        CustomLinkedList::new,
                        CustomLinkedList::addNewElement,
                        (list1, list2) -> list1.mergeWith(list2)
                )
        );
```

`Collector.of` has three parameters:

1. The supplier to use, in your case `CustomLinkedList`.
2. The function of how to add elements to your supplier.
3. The function that returns the result of two merged different `CustomLinkedList` `list1` and `list2`in my example, this function is necessary when using parallel stream processing.

For more details with example see this [link](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/).

Comment: So how do I deal with the static reference in CustomLinkedList::addNewElement? I am not sure how to implement this

Comment: In your case, you can replace addNewElement with addFirst or addLast.